# how to bind dataset to a treeview in asp.net c#?

Tags: asp.net, treeview

is there a way to bind a asp.net tree view control to a data set?

i am having to build the nodes of the tree by looping through a data set and wanted to clean it up and make life better buy just doing a .databind()

also XML is always an option if its simpler than dataset here...

any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Philb28 suggested, you can use a `SiteMapProvider` to handle this. I used that exact method on an old project. If you have a relatively static set of items for the `TreeView`, you can do the following:

1. Add a `.sitemap` file to your project.
2. Define `<sitemap>` and `<provider>` sections in your Web.config
3. Add sitemap elements to the provider section.

Here's what one of my Web.config sections looks like:

```
    <siteMap>
        <providers>
            <add name="Administrators" description="Reads .sitemap XML files." type="System.Web.XmlSiteMapProvider, System.Web, Version=2.0.3600.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" siteMapFile="Common/Sitemaps/Admins.sitemap"/>
            <add name="Users" description="Reads .sitemap XML files." type="System.Web.XmlSiteMapProvider, System.Web, Version=2.0.3600.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" siteMapFile="Common/Sitemaps/Users.sitemap"/>
        </providers>
    </siteMap>
```

From there, declare a `SiteMapDataSource`, set its `SiteMapProvider` property to the name property of one of your provider elements, and bind it. Finally, set your `TreeView.DataSource` to your `SiteMapDataSource`, and bind your TreeView as well.

Answer (score 0):

You could look into implementing your own [sitemapprovider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.staticsitemapprovider.aspx). You could then build your site map based on your data set and bind this to your tree view.